# NodeJS is Single Threaded - still not blocking in case of infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I am confused between how NodeJS is non-blocking even though it is single threaded platform. Especially, in this code i have two callbacks with one containing an infinite loop. It never shows expected output, in my case, 'thread2', but it keeps on executing the next callback at specified interval which in my opinion defies the fact of single threaded application. Any clarification would be highly appreciated.

```js
setInterval(() => console.log('thread1'), 1000);

setInterval(() => function() {
  console.log('thread2');
  while (true) {}
}, 500);

console.log('starting');
```

Comment: Remove the `"function()"` characters from the above code if you intend for the body of your function to be called by the `setInterval()`. Then, it will hit the infinite loop and nothing will progress. You aren't calling your infinite loop as it is. As it is you have an arrow function that is called by the `setInterval()`, but all it does is return another function that is never called. This appears like it's probably an arrow function typo coding mistake that happens to not create a syntax error.  Once you start executing the code in the inner function, you will see the expected infinite loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
() => function() {
  console.log('thread2');
  while (true) {}
}
```

This is a lambda expression (`() =>`) that returns a function (the value after that).  You never actually call that function.

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out why that was the case. It might be clearer if you gave an example of it written without any arrow functions. http://jsbin.com/sasuhizuce/1/edit?js,console

Comment: gotcha! That was one simple mistake. It works as expected now. Thanks